# Eclipse 2021-09 is not showing outline for javascript files

Tags: javascript, eclipse, wildwebdeveloper, eclipse-2021-09

I have eclipse 2021-09 (4.21.0) installed with Wild Web Developer 0.11.0 and Node.js embedder included. Javascript files are opened with Generic Text Editor, syntax highlighting is shown but outline view is empty. Even for the most simple *.js files. Take a look at the included screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

What might be wrong? How to fix it?

**EDIT:**

The same problems exist in a fresh, newly created workspace, with the same example javascript file.

Quick Outline (Ctrl+O) produces `java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException` with the following message: *LanguageServer not initialized after 10s*

Exception Stack Trace:

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.timedGet(CompletableFuture.java:1950)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:2085)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4e.LanguageServerWrapper.getServerCapabilities(LanguageServerWrapper.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4e.LanguageServiceAccessor.lambda$12(LanguageServiceAccessor.java:557)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:176)
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4e.LanguageServiceAccessor.getLSPDocumentInfosFor(LanguageServiceAccessor.java:558)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4e.operations.symbols.LSPSymbolInFileHandler.execute(LSPSymbolInFileHandler.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:283)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:97)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:317)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:487)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.executeCommand(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.press(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.processKeyEvent(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:647)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.filterKeySequenceBindings(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher$KeyDownFilter.handleEvent(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.filterEvent(Display.java:1270)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1059)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1084)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1069)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1111)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1107)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.wmChar(Widget.java:1536)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_CHAR(Control.java:4875)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.WM_CHAR(Canvas.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4753)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4958)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3624)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1150)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1041)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:551)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)
```

Session data:

```
eclipse.buildId=4.21.0.I20210906-0500
java.version=15.0.1
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Does updating Wild Web Developer via the update site [`https://download.eclipse.org/wildwebdeveloper/releases/latest/`](https://download.eclipse.org/wildwebdeveloper/releases/latest/) help? If not, is there something in the log?

Comment: Eclipse is reporting that the WWD is up to date. Not really sure what should I look for in the log.

Comment: See the [answer by the WWD developer Mickael](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69246512/6505250). It seems there is an issue when more than one plugin that uses the Generic Text Editor providing content for the _Outline_ view (maybe in your case, PyDev). You might use the Quick Outline view (Ctrl+O) as a workaround.

Comment: Ctrl+O produces java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException with the following message: LanguageServer not initialized after 10s

Comment: I have not seen that yet. Is this just the first time, or always? Do you get the same result with a fresh workspace?

Comment: @howlger Always. I have added the exception stack trace to my original question. I will update my answer once I find some time and try it out with a fresh workspace. Meanwhile I'll code javascript in Notepad++.

Comment: I vote to close this question because your question lacks basic and important information, but you refuse to answer follow-up questions, ignore the answer from the WWD lead, crop the log (no, the part you added is not helpful) and the screenshot. With the little information given, the issue cannot be reproduced.

Comment: @howlger All follow up questions have been answered except those that require extra time. Answer is not ignored, word 'seems' doesn't give a guarantee that the question is answered. The log is not cropped, it scrolls to the bottom. If you want other log, ask for it. Screenshot is showing the relevant part, you don't need the full workspace with a private project. Anything else?

Comment: When asking a question or when reporting a bug, make sure that the issue can be reproduced. I can not reproduce your issue. With the given information, one doesn't even know the basic things: which operating system?, which Eclipse IDE package?, which Java VM used to run Eclipse? These basic information would be included in the error log starting with `!SESSION` and the operating system can be seen in an uncropped screenshot. From the cropped screenshot it seems you have installed PyDev and switched to its perspective (which is not mentioned in your question).

Comment: The expected response to the answer by the WWD lead would have been, yes, it only happens with PyDev installed (or another plugin that you have installed), or it also happens even without any additional plugins installed in the Eclipse JEE IDE. You steal other people's time by telling irrelevant things. Switching to a fresh workspace and opening a JavaScript file takes less than a minute. Please delete your question and undelete it when you have this minute and another minute to respond to the given answer.

Comment: @howlger Awesome, I have updated my question with the data you asked for. In case you are still not able to reproduce the bug it doesn't mean that it doesn't exist. This is StackOverflow and not Eclipse Bugzilla. Someone else might have had the same problem and managed to solve it.

Comment: No, I didn't ask for some lines from the beginning of the log, nor for a _"I will look into this answer later"_ comment, nor whether this here is Stack Overflow. Either something is wrong with your installation, or/and there is a bug somewhere. It is up to you to track it down and if it is a bug, make sure it has been reported to the appropriate project (not all Eclipse projects use Eclipse Bugzilla and the screenshot shows that you have also non-Eclipse projects).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a symptom of https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper/issues/294 . Monitor the issue for potential workarounds and resolutions.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I will accept it as an answer once I confirm it solves my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers (includes Incubating components) Version: 2023-03 (4.27.0) Build id: 20230309-1520
OS: Windows 11
I was facing the same problem and tried various means but failed. But your new edit on "LanguageServer not initialized after 10s" made a lightbulb glow inside my head. I remembered that earlier I had stopped the Language Server from running in the background as it was constantly bugging me. So, I went ahead and started the same, this time only for Javascript content types.
[Windows -> Preferences -> Language Servers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsHN3.png)

Voila !!! Thereafter, my outline started appearing. Wanted to share this with you folks just in case it helps. Thanks